# Can Spotlight show results for disconnected drives?

Tags: spotlight, external-disk

I have several external hard drives which I would like to search for files with Spotlight. They cannot be all connected at the same time.

How can I get Spotlight results for offline external hard drives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, Spotlight stores the search index in the root folder of the volume. When the volume is disconnected, you cannot get search results from it.