# How to stop 'locate' from using databases for unmounted volumes?

Tags: macos, terminal, mount

Despite the claim made in the answer to this question:

- [Can Spotlight show results for disconnected drives?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/66275/13541)

This is exactly the behaviour I am seeing and I don't want it!

E.g.

```
wms:~ alan$ ls /Volumes
MobileBackups   Tamandua    
wms:~ alan$ locate /usr/texbin
/Volumes/AlanG5Backup/Previous Systems/Previous System 1/usr/texbin
/Volumes/AlanG5Backup/Previous Systems.localized/2009-07-10_1136/usr/texbin
/Volumes/MacBookBackup/usr/texbin
```

`AlanG5Backup` and `MacBookBackup` were partitions that I had previously mounted, but (as the output from `ls /Volumes` shows) were not mounted when I ran the `locate` command.

Furthermore, the current volume (Tamandua) doesn't show any `locate` results at all, which it should.

How do I fix this?  I'm running 10.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`locate` is not equivalent to `Spotlight`**.

Having said that, lets look at the meat of your question:

You can try to force an update of the locate db using `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` which will rebuild the locates database.

I would check the `manpage` for locate for additional options regarding other volumes as I believe there is a flag to stay on the current filesystem from locate but it escapes me at the moment. [Locate Man Page for 10.9](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/locate.1.html)

Having looked at it the best thing I can come up with is to use a regular expression that won't visit another filesystem or to create seperate databases for each.

Another option is to use the `find` command which can be told to stay on the current filesystem `-x` on BSD, `-xdev` in linux.

Comment: Thanks. Updating the database cleared up the problem, but it's still odd that it happens in the first place.

Comment: When the locate updater run last, the external drives were attached and therefore indexed. `locate` just looks in the database for any matches and doesn't take mount/unmount status into account at all.